# Why doesn't my oData response have navigation properties

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, asp.net-web-api

If you look at the following sample oData feed you'll see included navigation properties for 'child' items to tell you which URL to follow:

> [http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?$format=json](http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?%24format=json)

For example supplier 0 has a navigation property to products.
This links to a list of products for that supplier.

> [http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers(0)/Products?$format=json](http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers%280%29/Products?%24format=json)

---

I'm trying to do the same with `ODataConventionModelBuilder` and `EntitySetController<Product>` so that when I request `oData/Product(0)` it will show me the 'features' for the product:

I create my model like this (based on [GetImplicitEdmModel sample](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/ODataServiceSample/ODataService/ModelBuilder.cs))

```
     // odata
     ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
     modelBuilder.EntitySet<RRStoreDB.Models.Product>("Product");
     modelBuilder.EntitySet<RRStoreDB.Models.ProductFeature>("ProductFeature");

     Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
     config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
```

I create a controller for WebAPI :

```
public class  ProductController : EntitySetController<Product, int>
{
    RRStoreDBContext _db = new RRStoreDBContext();


    [Queryable]
    public override IQueryable<DProduct> Get()
    {
        return _db.Products.AsQueryable();
    }

    public ICollection<ProductFeature> GetProductFeatures(int key)
    {
        Product product = _db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == key);
        if (product == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return product.ProductFeatures;
    }
}
```

When I actually call the URL for my child property it works and gives me the correct list of features :

```
 /oData/Products(18)/ProductFeatures
```

However I would have expected a navigation property in `/oData/Products(18)` pointing to this.

What do I need to do to get this to appear. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/11/02/odata-in-webapi-microsoft-asp-net-web-api-odata-0-2-0-alpha-release.aspx) says it's automatic but I'm not seeing them:

> The ODataConventionModelBuilder, which is generally recommended over
>   the ODataModelBuilder, will automatically infer inheritance
>   hierarchies in the absence of explicit configuration. Then once the
>   hierarchy is inferred, it will also infer properties and navigation
>   properties too. This allows you to write less code, focusing on where
>   you deviate from our conventions.

Comment: I found a sample that does basically what I'm doing - and it too has no navigation properties - how can I enable them - or is this not supported? http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ODataServiceSample/ODataService/Controllers/ProductsController.cs

Comment: I think I'm officially giving up on this already. oData is just too complicated!

Comment: Hi @Simon_Weaver, I did exactly as you but the error I get is: `Not implemented, This service doesn't support OData requests in the form '~/entityset/key/unresolved'.`   You could solve the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are asking for `application/json`. `application/json` in web API OData points to json light which is the latest OData json representation aimed at reducing response payload sizes and trimming the un-necessary/redundant metadata from the response. For comparison, try getting the url `~/oData/Products(18)` with accept header `application/json;odata=verbose`.

Now, the idea behind json light is that if a link can be calculated because the link follows conventions, it will not be put in the response. The navigation link `/oData/Products(18)/ProductFeatures` is a perfect example of that. It follows OData uri conventions.

OData json light has 3 modes, minimalmetadata (the default), fullmetadata and nometadata. The names are themselves explanatory. If you want the link to be on the wire, send the request with accept header `application/json;odata=fullmetadata`.

Refer to this [document](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/47421/Json%20Overview%202012-11-08.docx) to understand more about json light.

Comment: great - that did it! is there any way to force full JSON when calling from a browser where it's harder to set the accept headers

Comment: Instead of `$format=json` in the URL, try `$format=application/json;odata=fullmetadata`. If you're consuming OData from javascript, you might be interested in the [datajs](http://datajs.codeplex.com/) library. As far as I know, datajs requests fullmetadata under the hood, but it abstracts out some of those details for you.

Comment: web API OData doesn't support $format out-of-the-box. It is very easy to add support for $format though using a message handler. I have a sample [here](https://gist.github.com/raghuramn/5556691)