# Posting Collection to OData Controller not returning nested collection property to client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have the following Model class defined:

```
public class LinePostModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public IList<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
    }
```

and this method on my OData Controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(LinePostModel model)
{
  //validae model and its OrderLines collection and save to repo.

  return Created(model);
}
```

The server receives the model object correctly, and processes every find.  My problem is that the RESPONSE that is returned to the client only contains the primitive OrderId property, and does NOT contain the collection property OrderLines.

How can I fix this so that the entire complex object is returned to the client?

EDIT: added sample json:

Here is what the client posts:

```
{
      orderId:4,
      orderLines: [
        {
            lineType: "S",
            orderQty: 10,
            priceCode: "D",
            stockCode: "62.C6W026A.050",
            warehouse: "GS",
            orderId:4
        },
        {
            lineType: "S",
            orderQty: 20,
            priceCode: "D",
            stockCode: "62.C6W026A.060",
            warehouse: "GS",
            orderId:4
        }
      ]
}
```

and here is what the client receives back from the server:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://localhost:4095/$metadata#OrderLines/$entity",
  "orderId": 4
}
```

I have tried changing the server to return `Ok(model)` instead of `Created(model)`, but it makes no difference.

A breakpoint on the `return Created(model)` line in the controller method shows that at that point the model object definitely contains the collection of OrderLines.

Comment: what does OrderLines contain in client side? is it null?

Comment: When the client invokes the Post method, the model is correctly populated and deserialized on the server side.  The problem is when the server returns the Created response to the client, that response object does not contain the OrderLines property at all.

Comment: I haven't used Created so far when returning result. I use `return Ok(model);` for returning content. You can try with that.

Comment: Have tried with both Ok(model) and Created(model) but to no avail.

Comment: You can post client side script where you are retrieving data

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue. Were you able tot solve this?

Comment: @nidhimj22 nope...never did...I ended up changing my design to post individual lines...sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I had trouble with the same issue, please try this:

```
http://localhost:4095/odata/LinePostModel?$expand=OrderLines
```

[image]

Comment: Give a bit more detail here Oliver. Perhaps a link to the ODATA documentation that shows what the expand parameter does.

Comment: I read something about that in all http methods ODATA from microsoft, I don't have the docs by hand. But in your POST request you can specify how you want to be the response. In the example that I wrote I am saying that I want the nested objects "LinePostModel" in the response. I gues you saw expand query options sometimes if not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/concepts/queryoptions-overview

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to go on but if you are using Entity Framework to save to the repo remember to add `.Include()` when retrieving the saved record also to return child records.

Comment: Thanks for the input Andre, but nope, that is not the issue...a breakpoint on the return Created(model) shows that the model definitely has the OrderLines property populated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this answer response and see if this helps. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472870/1233465

You can try adding the accept header in your request and see if that helps. Please share your results and findings.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the parent class you can just return the List<orderLines>.

```
return Created(model.orderLines);
```

I realized this when someone else mentioned they returned string being the JSON serialization of the whole complex object.  If they could return string, I could return List<childObject>.

Answer (score 0):

Is OrderLine an entity as well, or a complex property?

You need to make sure that the EDM model defined in your WebApiConfig.cs has the above relationship mapped correctly. For starters, you should check /$metadata during runtime.

If the EDM model does not have the right relationship, then ODATA pipeline will strip out the extra information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me OrderLine was defined as an entity type. Same type cannot be both entity and complex type because complex type does not have an 'Id' property. Make sure OrderLine is not set as EntityType. If that does not work, try setting it as 'ComplexType' explicitly.