# How to Post Collection to OData Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

How can I configure my OData model to execute the following:

```
POST /api/OrderHeaders(id)/OrderLines
```

such that the body of the post contains a collection of order lines to be posted to the associated orderHeader?

Is this approach supported in OData?

Looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4#creating-a-relationship-between-entities) it seems that oData only supports creating relationships between existing entities, while what I am trying to do is to CREATE related entities.

An alternative approach I've tried is to execute the following:

```
POST /api/OrderLines
```

Once again, the body of the post contains a collection of order line objects.  But this method on the server side always has an empty model:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(List<OrderLine> model)
{
}
```

The json just does not serialize to the expected model.

So once again I changed my approach, where I have a model defined as follows:

```
public class LinePostModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
    }
```

and my OData controller method as follows:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(LinePostModel model)
{
}
```

This approach works as far as validating and saving the model to the database is concerned.  But it leaves me with a different problem I have posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523855/posting-collection-to-odata-controller-not-returning-nested-collection-property).

Does oData support the concept of posting a collection to a controller, and then returning that same collection to the client?  If so, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to either of your posts?

Comment: Nope...never did.  So instead, we went with the approach of posting order lines one-by-one to the server, instead of in a collection.  Which actually worked out better for our specific scenario.  If you MUST post the collection in an all-or-nothing approach, then go with the design in the other question I referred to above, and do a GET to retrieve the posted lines after a success POST result.